# Suppress indentation on the opening line of a letter

Tags: indentation, letters

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\signature{Doorknob}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
    \noindent \opening{Dear TeX Stack Exchange,}

    Waffles are pancakes with built-in syrup reservoirs.

    Unicorns are magically weaponized ponies.

    This is a generic paragraph.

    \closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

When I try viewing a document created with that code, the opening line ("Dear TeX Stack Exchange") is still indented, despite the `\noindent` command.

How can I tell LaTeX not to indent the opening line of a letter?

Comment: Drop the `\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}` line by `%` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Heh, well I suppose that does solve *one* problem... :P

Comment: Is there *another one*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `letter` class is built on the assumption that `\parindent` is zero.

Patch the `\opening` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\opening}{#1}{\noindent#1}{}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

\signature{Doorknob}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Some Body\\
  Some Where\\
  42 Some Street}

\opening{Dear TeX Stack Exchange,}

Waffles are pancakes with built-in syrup reservoirs.

Unicorns are magically weaponized ponies.

This is a generic paragraph.

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `opening` line by:

```
\opening{\noindent Dear TeX Stack Exchange,}
```

Comment: Great; this worked perfectly! I'll accept this answer (in 4 minutes when I can) because there's only one opening anyway, so this is easier than the `patchcmd` solution in the other answer.

Comment: Why is that? Is there any reason that his solution would work better than this one?

Comment: No, it's the same solution essentially.  He just provided an explanation...  :-)